# Convolution of H(-t) and H(t)

Tags: convolution

I have a problem in signals and systems to solve which is basically math

So suppose we have two functions x(t) = H(t) which is the Heaviside unit step function as input and an impulse response

$$h(t)=e^{-\left | t \right |} + e^{-\left | 2t \right |}$$

which is $$h(t)=(e^t+e^{2t})H(-t)+(e^{-t}+e^{-2t})H()t)$$

We want to calculate the convolution between them.

At a point i have reached this integral

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }(e^\tau + e^{2\tau })H(-\tau )H(t-\tau )d\tau $$

I think it is zero but I cannot explain why this is true

Any help is welcome

Comment: Writing out the heaviside functions should result in $\int_{- \infty}^{\min(t, 0)} e^{\tau} + e^{2 \tau} \; \text{d} \tau$, which is non-zero.